# Increment the ID for every addition of elements in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops

i am having a problem where i cannot able to increment the ID of the state element for every addition of elements in the row. What i am getting is same number is repeating for every addition of elements, i need something like ID should be 1 to n numbers of addition.
In text-box, i am not entering the ID, i enter only the LText(Name).
In general, the ID should generate for every addition of elements.
What i have tried is..

```
    export default class EPIM091 extends cntrl.WITBase {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        const witState = this.state;
        if (Object.keys(witState).length == 0) {
            witState.model = { LID: 1, LText: '', SOrder: '', Inventoried: false, Location:[] }; //Here i need to store all other state values to the Location Array
}
}
 clickAction = (e) => {
if (e.id == 'btn_add') {
            //var i = 1;
            const { model } = this.state;
            if (model.LText != null) {
                if ((model.Location || []).length == 0) {
                    model.Location = [];
                }
                // this.setState(prevState => { return { LID: e.id == 'btn_add' ? prevState.LID + 1 : prevState.LID - 1 } }); //This does not worked
                model.Location.push({ "LID": model.LID.toString(), "LText": model.LText, "SOrder": model.SOrder, "Inventoried": model.Inventoried.toString() });
                this.setState({
                    model: model,
                    LID: model.LID + 1 //This also not worked
                });
            }
        }
    };
       render(){
// Due to confusion of code, i did not add the textboxes codes
<cntrl.WITButton id="btn_add" onWitClick={this.clickAction} />
}
```

[image]

I need something like when i add, i should get the Unique LID from 1 to the number of elements added. What i am getting is same ID i.e 1. Thank you

Comment: Your code is poorly formatted and extremely difficult to read
also what is  cntrl.WITBase that you are extending? and you are not giving your component any state inside of the constructor.

Comment: i) cntrl.WITBase is a Base class, no need to worry about that.
ii) const witState = this.state; i stored this.state to witState and utilized in the constructor. Please refer once.

Comment: how are you accessing your LID after you have set it with setState?

Comment: I store all the values to Location[] and using (dataSource: model.Location) and (field: 'LText'), i access the elements and display it. What i just need is after adding the elements, the LID should get generated by 1 to... number of rows are added.

Comment: Have you understand my problem?

Comment: I don't think you are accessing the LID value using this.state.LID
and you should not extend a base class in react other than the Component class.

Comment: How to access the LID value?

Comment: Forget about the WITBase extends, its not a problem

Comment: using this.state.LID just wrote it in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Many problems here :

1) You are trying to modify a variable that you declared constant:

```
const witState = this.state;
        if (Object.keys(witState).length == 0) {
            witState.model = { LID: 1, LText: '', SOrder: '', Inventoried: false, Location:[] };
```

2) You are trying to access state variable, but you never define it:

```
const { model } = this.state;
```

3) You try to modify it even if it's declared constant:

```
if (model.LText != null) {
                if ((model.Location || []).length == 0) {
                    model.Location = [];
                }
                // this.setState(prevState => { return { LID: e.id == 'btn_add' ? prevState.LID + 1 : prevState.LID - 1 } }); //This does not worked
                model.Location.push({ "LID": model.LID.toString(), "LText": model.LText, "SOrder": model.SOrder, "Inventoried": model.Inventoried.toString() });
                this.setState({
                    model: model,
                    LID: model.LID + 1 //This also not worked
                });
            }
```

Unless there is a lot of code you didn't show us, you must have a lot of errors in your console. Watch it.

**-[Edit]-**:

The problem is that I can't really help you unless I have the whole code, because as it is, it doesn't make sense. If you just want to increment your LID state var, here is a working example:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state={LID:1}
}
test=(e)=>{
    let {LID} = this.state;
    this.setState({LID:LID+1})
    console.log(this.state.LID);
 }
 render(){
     return(
         <button onClick={this.test}> Test</button>
     )
 }
```

Comment: By incrementing in setState, i am getting solution, but react docs says not to increment in the setState.
this.setState({
                    LID: this.state.model.LID++
                }, function () {

                    model.Location.push({ "LID": this.state.LID + 1, "LText": model.LText, "SOrder": model.SOrder, "Inventoried": model.Inventoried.toString() });

                    this.setState({
                        model: model
                    });
                });

Comment: I edited my answer with a working example, so you can see what could work.